# Should I use reflection to count a property present in two or more entities?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, repository

**Goal**

I would like to be able to count the number of times a specific `PrimaryImageId` is used within a number of different db entities.

Their classes each have a `PrimaryImageId` property and are adorned with a `[HasPrimaryImage]` attribute. They also implement an interface `IHasPrimaryImage`.

*I may not know these classes in advance, so I want to use the `[HasPrimaryImage]` attribute to identify them, not hard code in the types.*

**I've Tried**

I am using a generic repository method.  But although it works when called with 'hard-coded' types:

```
GetCount<NewsItem>(x => x.PrimaryImageId == id);
```

...I can't get it to work when the type argument is provided from reflection.

```
var types = GetTypesWithHasPrimaryImageAttribute();
foreach(Type t in types)
{
    GetCount<t>(x => x.PrimaryImageId == id);
}
```

I've tried calling `GetCount<t>()`, `GetCount<typeof(t)>` and a few other silly things.

It appears that [I can't call a generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method) using a reflection generated `type`.

**Question**

Jon Skeet [recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/1778169) using `MakeGenericMethod` in his answer, but I'm struggling to do that and wondering if that is overkill for my requirements. Is there an easier / better way to achieve what I'm after?

---

---

**Db Entity Classes**

```
[HasPrimaryImage]
public class NewsItem 
{
    public int PrimaryImageId { get; set; }

    // .. other properties
}


[HasPrimaryImage]
public class Product 
{
    public int PrimaryImageId { get; set; }

    // .. other properties
}
```

**Generic Repository Method**

```
public virtual int GetCount<TDataModel>(Expression<Func<TDataModel, bool>> wherePredicate = null)
    where TDataModel : class, IDataModel
{
    return GetQueryable<TDataModel>(wherePredicate).Count();
}
```

**Get All Classes with `HasPrimaryImage` Attribute:**

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesWithHasPrimaryImageAttribute()
{
    var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    foreach (Type type in currentAssembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HasPrimaryImageAttribute), true).Length > 0)
        {
            yield return type;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in general skeet provides the correct answer. In particular you want to specify the type for a generic method at run time. MakeGenericMethod is how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have obtained the `MethodInfo`, then you can use its `MakeGenericMethod` method to specify its generic type argument before making the call via reflection.

```
MethodInfo getCountMethod = my Objectives. GetType() .GetMethod(
    "GetCount", 
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | ...); // Fill the right flags

var types = GetTypesWithHasPrimaryImageAttribute();
Func<Entity, bool> predicate = x => x.PrimaryImageId == id;

foreach(Type t in types)
{
     getCountMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(myObj, predicate);
}
```

I haven't been able to run this code, so please forgive me if there is some omission there. But this should be the working principle and you will be able to make it work for you.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful.  Is `myObj` a normally instantiated instance of the generic repository?

Comment: I suppose it is - that is the object on which the `GetCount` method is defined. Now you pull that out into a `MethodInfo`, fill the generic type in and then invoke it by passing the same `myObj` as the instance on which the method should execute.

Comment: Your example uses `myObj` both as a type (the call to `GetMethod`) and an instance of that type (the call to `Invoke`). The first of those should really be `myType` (assuming you have a `Type` with that name)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 - so glad you said that, I really struggled to make it work, until I passed an *instance* of the repository in instead of the type.  Your comment affirms I've done it correctly. No disrespect to Zoran who did 99% of the work for me in order to get it working! Really big thanks to both of you.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Sorry, I missed the call to GetType(). Now it's fixed but you've figured it already.